# JavaScript: how to return a value from a asyn function in a for loop

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, return-value

I got a Service as follows to return back a value:

```
// Service.js
var done = false;
var readyToSubmit = function(answerArr, len) {
  var threshold = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < answerArr.length; i++) {
    var id = answerArr[i].focus + '_' + userData.uid;
    appStore.getDoc(id).then(function(doc) {
      if (doc.doneRate == 100) {
        threshold++;
        if (threshold == len) {
          done = true;
        } else {
          done = false;
        }
      }
    });
  }
  return done; // here, It always returns 'undefined'.
};
```

I would like to use this service in my AngularJs project, like below:

```
var answerArr = $scope.homework.items;
var len = answerArr.length;
$scope.$on('appChange', function(e, doc) {
  $scope.done = hwService.readyToSubmit(answerArr, len);
});
```

However, always without luck, although I tried call `readyToSubmit(para1, para2, callback)`, this kind of calling doesn't make any fortune. It really bugs me for about 4 hours. So anyone would like to do me a favor here? Many many thanks~~ :)

Comment: You can't, that's what async means!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The point is you can not return the `done` variable because when you want to return it, the callback function in your for loop:

```
appStore.getDoc(id).then(function(doc) {
    //...
})
```

hasn't got called yet. since as you also mentioned in your question it is a `asynchronous function`.

You have 2 options, first is using Angular promises which is described in another answer, but you also have one other solution which is using a callback in `readyToSubmit` function:

```
var done = false;
var readyToSubmit = function(answerArr, len, callback) {
  var threshold = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < answerArr.length; i++) {
    var id = answerArr[i].focus + '_' + userData.uid;
    appStore.getDoc(id).then(function(doc) {
      if (doc.doneRate == 100) {
        threshold++;
        if (threshold == len) {
          callback(true);
        } else {
          callback(false);
        }
      }
    });
  }
  //no need to return anything
  //return done;
};
```

then to use in your angular scope:

```
var answerArr = $scope.homework.items;
var len = answerArr.length;
$scope.$on('appChange', function(e, doc) {
  hwService.readyToSubmit(answerArr, len, function(done){
      $scope.done = done;
  });
});
```

this way, the point that you have to consider is, this line of code:

```
$scope.done = done;
```

would get called more than once.

Comment: I've tried this callback method before, as I mentioned. But got no luck...yeap, the following line of code will be definitely called more than once:
    $scope.done = done;
I will try this again...many thanks, if it works, mark it true, thanks again...

Answer (score 0):

You can't use async functions like this.

You can use angulars promise to achieve this.

```
// Service.js
var done = false;
var defered = $q.defer() //include in service function $q
var readyToSubmit = function(answerArr, len) {
  var threshold = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < answerArr.length; i++) {
    var id = answerArr[i].focus + '_' + userData.uid;
    appStore.getDoc(id).then(function(doc) {
      if (doc.doneRate == 100) {
        threshold++;
        if (threshold == len) {
          defered.resolve(true);
        } else {
          done = false;
        }           
      }
    });
  }
  return done; // here, It always returns 'undefined'.
};
```

Use a defer object to make use of the angular promise. 
if `defered.resolve()` is called, it will invoke the `.then`.

```
var answerArr = $scope.homework.items;
var len = answerArr.length;
$scope.$on('appChange', function(e, doc) {
  hwService.readyToSubmit(answerArr, len).then(function(done){
    $scope.done = done;
  });
});
```

Comment: thanks, buddy..this one makes not fortune in my project~~but it's a alternative way for other projects~~: )